# PHP - How to update to 7.0 full release from the release candidate

Tags: php, ubuntu

So I have dev box running ubuntu 14.04 and I have php version 7.0.0 RC8 and today the full release came out and I would like to update to it. However I can't seem to figure out the right commands to do so. Any help would be appreciated.

I did `apt-cache madison php7.0` and it returned:

`php7.0 | 7.0.0~rc8-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 | http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php-7.0/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages`

So it seems that for some reason my ubuntu doesn't realize that the release is out...ive done a apt-get update already so it SHOULD see it. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you install 7.0.0 RC8?

Comment: it came with my homestead vagrant  box ;)

Comment: does `homestead update` put you on the RTM? You could try `dpkg -l | grep php`, remove the package (`dpkg -r package`), and installing it manually.

Comment: yeah....im still a pretty mediocre linux guy so manually removing and installing all the packages that make up php 7 isn't an option

Comment: Wait for the package maintainer, or compile and install from source. (P.S.: Not a programming question.)